# Summary or Changelog of pull requests based on a comparison on Github

Tags: git, github, jira, commit, pull-request

I run a comparison between two branches in a repo during our promotion cycle, and I get a list of the squashed commits. I have to click into each of those commits to retrieve the pull request and the related JIRA ticket so that we can test the code for Quality Assurance. I would like a list of the PR's and if possible, the related JIRA tickets. I have the ability to influence how the developers format their commits, etc., and they follow this formatting for their commit messages: https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/

I have found comparing files and creating a PR, and various other types of summaries, but I'm specifically looking for a list of PR's given a comparison of branches in a single repo.

Comment: Are you writing an API client to retrieve a list of PR URL's for a given commit set?

Comment: I'm not writing an API. I just need a list of some sort that can show me the PR numbers/links of a given comparison.